# Have nginx load a specifc html file

Tags: nginx

I currently have a server block with many routes, I'm trying to have nginx load a report.html file.

What would I put inside this

```
location = /report.html {
    (what goes in here)
}
```

To get my site to load `example.com/report.html` from my directory `/var/log/report.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location = /report.html {
    alias  /var/log/report.html;
}
```